# Find a polynomial of degree $8$ with integer coefficients with given root

Tags: cryptography

algorithm to find a polynomial $f(x)$ s.t

**(1)** $degree(f(x))<9$

**(2)** Integer coefficients

**(3)** Absolute value of coefficients $< 10^5$

**(4)** f(39.770525) =~ 0  about to be  <<10^-10

I heard that it is similar to coppersmith algorithm, but I can't find why